# How to call external js file from jQuery on page load

Tags: jquery

I have partial view for rating. This view is repeated multiple time on a single page.
I have written the functional code for rating in an external js file.
Now I want to call that js file each time rating view is loaded.
Also I want to pass parameter to the external js file.
I have tried the following method to do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
  var EntityId="@ViewData["entityid"]";// parameters which i want to pass
  var RatingValue="@ViewData["rating"]";// parameters which i want to pass
  var EntityName="@ViewData["entityname"]";// parameters which i want to pass
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/RatingControl.js"></script>
```

The code above is working but the external script only access last value of passed variable
e.g. there is 5 records on my page then the rating control will be added 5 time with different value. But in external file I only get last records rating value.

So how can I call external js file from javascript code on each partial view load event.

Answer (score 2):

Try using jquery [**.getScript()**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) , that way you can control the order your scripts are executed, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
 var EntityId="@ViewData["entityid"]";// parameters which i want to pass
 var RatingValue="@ViewData["rating"]";// parameters which i want to pass
 var EntityName="@ViewData["entityname"]";// parameters which i want to pass
 $.getScript("../../Scripts/RatingControl.js");

 //second time
 var EntityId="new value";// parameters which i want to pass
 var RatingValue="new value";// parameters which i want to pass
 var EntityName="new value";// parameters which i want to pass
 $.getScript("../../Scripts/RatingControl.js");
</script>
```

Comment: thanks nelson it works, but in external file i get only last records entity id